# Service Wire Burn

Tags: transformer, wire, distribution-network

I have a Distribution Transformer rated 25kVA 14.4/240 kV installed in the system. One phase of the serving 3 phase line of our electric utility in 23kV primary side are faulted in Line to ground unfortunately the bundled line-to-line service wire going to our premises was burned. What would possibly happened?

I was wondering why among all the other customer in that common single phase transformer, only our service wire was burned that results into some equipment damage.

Comment: Could you clean up your question?  You talk about 3-phase, then single-phase.  Which is it?  You also mention 240 kV - not sure how that fits into this question.

Comment: @DwayneReid: I think it is a pole-mount transformer with an output rated as \$25kVA\$ at \$14.4kV\$, running single phase with a primary specified for a \$240VAC\$ at \$100A\$ service. These are very standard pole transformers. The only thing I'm unsure about is whether this is a \$120/240V\$ primary or a \$240/480V\$ primary. They also go the other way, so I'm also not sure about that part. Maybe he's pulling from one phase of a three-phase system to get his 100A service?

Comment: @DwayneReid: a 1x25kV pole mounted transformer with rating 14.4kV:120/240V. Primary Bushing is connected to one phase in a three-phase system and the other bushing to the ground. When LG fault in primary (I'm not sure what phase) occurs the service wire going to our premises which connected in the low volage side of the transformer was burned. My question is Why is it burned when the fault happened in primary side? What is the other possible cause of service wire burned? please help. thanks

Comment: Wire burning is caused by a high fault current ... From this description it sounds like the Branch Circuit Protection (BCP / fuse) failed to trip or the fault occurred before the fuse. So the question is ... whats changed to cause the fault? I don't believe anything on the primary could cause this.

Comment: @JamesC: Your question still says 240 kV (1/4 million volts). Can you edit to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hypothesis is the following series of events:

(1) A line on the primary side of the transformer faults to ground (neutral) as you describe.

(2) However, due to the neutral impedance (or a problem with the neutral), the fault current raises the neutral potential by several thousand volts.

(3) The primary-side utility neutral is typically connected to a grounding rod at the pole -- and also to the center tap of the secondary for split-phase service (120/240 VAC). You mention a line-to-line service, which implies that no neutral conductor (or grounded conductor) runs to the house. I'm not familiar with that configuration, but I'll assume there's no neutral going to the house.

(4) With the utility's neutral connected to the secondary center tap, the common-mode voltage of the secondary now rises by several thousand volts during the fault.

(5) At some point in the service entry or premises wiring, the high common-mode voltage of the service conductors arcs over to a grounded enclosure or other grounded conductor. The fault current from this arc burns the service wires and damages equipment.

(6) If the supply lines in your house arced to ground before your neighbor's, your neighbors may have been spared from any damage.